# Chrome Extensions: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension and have this call in my background page:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {console.log(details)}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

However whenever I run it I get this error in the dev tools for the background page:

```
Error during webRequestInternal.addEventListener: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners. Be sure to declare the webRequestBlocking permission in your manifest.
```

Even though my permissions in my manifest look like so:

```
"permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs",
        "history",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
```

What the heck is going on here? Here's the web request docs http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/webRequest.html.

Answer (score 2):

Works good for me with following code, why do you want to do it in a background page in specific?

**Screen Shot**

[image]

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"name":"My First App",
"description":"This is First App",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"permissions": [
        "cookies",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs",
        "history",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
"icons":{"16":"icon.jpg"},
"background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_icon":"icon.jpg"
}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
console.log(details);
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

**Background.js**

```
function doNothing(){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was writing my first Chrome extension:
My solution was to **remove the extension**, fix the **manifest.json** and **add the extension again**. Just deactivating it and re-activating it won't do the trick.

I loaded the extension into Chrome and started to debug. When I found an error in the code, I **deactivated** the extension, fixed the bug an **activated** the extension again. This worked fine to fix code errors. But when I tried to use the webrequest module in a blocking fashion I always got "*Error during webRequestInternal.addEventListener: You do not have permission to use blocking webRequest listeners. Be sure to declare the webRequestBlocking permission in your manifest.*". No matter how I changed the manifest.json.

Answer (score -2):

Going to manifest version 2 instead of 3 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: this is not a fix... v2 is about to be removed altogether